# Has anyone been able to successfully execute SET RESULT_SET_CACHING on Azure SQL Warehouse?

Tags: azure, caching, azure-sql-database, query-optimization, database-administration

I currently have an Azure SQL data warehouse and I'd like to enable caching so that intensive queries run faster in the database with the following code:

ALTER DATABASE [myDB]
SET RESULT_SET_CACHING ON;

However, no matter how I try to run this query I get the following error:

Msg 5058, Level 16, State 12, Line 3

Option 'RESULT_SET_CACHING' cannot be set in database 'myDB'.

I am running the query based on Azure's documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options?view=azure-sqldw-latest

I have tried running this query both in the master database and in the underlying one called myDB. I have also tried using commands such as:

USE master

GO

With no avail. Has anyone had success in enabling caching on Azure? Please let me know!

Screenshot of error and command below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEJIy.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested and this command works well in my ADW dwleon, see the bellow screenshot:

[image]

Please make sure:

1. Login you Azure SQL data warehouse with SQL server Admin account.
2. Run this command in master db

Summary of the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options?view=azure-sqldw-latest#permissions):

- To set the RESULT_SET_CACHING option, a user needs server-level
  principal login (the one created by the provisioning process) or be a
  member of the `dbmanager` database role.
- [Enable result set caching for a database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options?view=azure-sqldw-latest#enable-result-set-caching-for-a-database):

  --Run this command when connecting to the MASTER database

  ```
  ALTER DATABASE [database_name]
  SET RESULT_SET_CACHING ON;
  ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am currently logged in with the administrator account in the data warehouse. I have also tried creating dummy accounts with the dbmanager role as well with no luck. I have automatic tuning enabled on the Azure portal do you know if this needs to be disabled prior to running this command?

Comment: I ran the command in the same way I thought you did but I get the same error message. I included a screenshot of the command and error message in my original post listed above. Thank you for helping me with this!

Comment: Please shows us the results of the query: select @@version

Comment: When I run that query I get the following: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Dec  4 2019 21:24:18   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation

Comment: So this is an Azure SQL Database not an Azure SQL Data Warehouse (now known as Azure Synapse Analytics).  It’s a separate product entirely.  See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/release-notes-10-0-10106-0

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, the Finance database is just an ordinary Azure SQL Database.  When it is a SQL Data Warehouse it shows up with a different icon - four golden cylinders, instead of one black black cylinder.